# Android - Get data from a dynamic EditTexts by ID

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have the code below in my adapter that creates dynamically EditTexts and set IDs using the method "et_settingValue.setId(setting.getId());".
An Editbox is created in every instace of the class Setting and it also contains a variable to store its id.

This part is already working properly, but now I need to access all those created EditTexts by ID and get its data. If possible, I would like to avoid creating another array to store the EditTexts because I already have their IDs.

Is there any way to do it using the dynamic IDs I already have?

```
EditText et_settingValue = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_settingValue);
et_settingValue.setText(setting.getValue().trim());
et_settingValue.setId(setting.getId());
```

### Update 1

In my activity, I am trying to do this:

```
EditText et = new EditText(listView.getContext());
//loop to get each object child 
settingConfig.getConfigName(); //ok
settingConfig.getConfigValue(); //ok
settingConfig.getConfigId(); //ok
et = (EditText) listView.findViewById(settingConfig.getConfigId()); //not working
et.getText(); // off course it will not working
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView use a RecycleBin to reuse the view created from Adapter, so ListView will only contain a few child view, and you cannot find all EditText in the ListView.

To solve your problem, you should use a Map to record the value of all EditText. Add TextWatcher to each of them, and refresh the value in the Map on text changed.

Comment: thank for your attentio @faylon....when you say map, is it any specific feature of Android or an array list (Editbox)?

Comment: oh... java.util.Map, java.util.HashMap... don't tell me you have never used it.